# python's datetime.timedelta for bash

Tags: python, bash

Is there in bash similar construction for this in python:

```
start_time = time.time()
target()
print datetime.timedelta( seconds= int(time.time() - start_time) )
```

?

I'm looking for any wrapper like `datetime.timedelta`.

I mean, easy construction: one/two line, that give the same result, days/hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: What do you need it for? The Python code does not show that.

Comment: to get human readable speed of target()

Answer (score 4):

Running the below will time the execution of the script you wish to time.

```
time script
```

For example:

```
time python my_script.py
```

Will time how long your script runs, independant of python itself. Similarly for `time ls -la .`, `time cat a_long_file`, `time du -h` etc...

[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)

Comment: Actually, i'm looking for way to convert int(seconds) to human readable speed of part of code. time du -h, will show exactly what i'm looking for but it is stderr, it is three lines, and manymore.

Comment: stacktrace, You can convert a epoch time string to a human readable form like this: date -d @1268727836 +"%d-%m-%Y %T %z" . Not sure if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @stacktrace You can capture different output streams separately using `time bash -c " 1>one 2>two" 2>three`, which should solve your problems.

Comment: Sridhar Jagannathan, i'm looking for convertion seconds in human readable period of time, e.g 4 days, 12:10:13, but 389413 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with bash:

```
$ start_time=`date +%s`; sleep 3; echo "took $((`date +%s` - start_time)) seconds"
```

Outputs:

```
took 3 seconds
```

Or just use `time` command.

Comment: Your example give me: "took 193 seconds", my python script give: "0:03:13"

Comment: @stacktrace did you suspend your computer while it was in `sleep`? lol